# Getting data to fragment class from async task

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am beginner in android. How can i get the data from **AsyncTask** to placeholder fragment2 class i cannot  access  actors list from the AsyncTask.If i get the data as a array in placement fragment i can use that to create a list view from the data retrieved from **async task**.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment2 extends Fragment {


    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    ListView list;
    ActorsAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;




    public static PlaceholderFragment2 newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment2 fragment = new PlaceholderFragment2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment2() {


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_json, container, false);
        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_news);
        actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();

        new ActorsAsyncTask().execute("https://myurl.com");



        //EDITED Code







        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MyActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

public static class ActorsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(strings[0]);


        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            if(data != null) {

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(data);
                String results = object.getString("results");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + results);

                JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject(results);
                JSONArray jArray = object1.getJSONArray("collection1");


                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    Actors actor = new Actors();
                    JSONObject object2 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    String property1 = object2.getString("property1");
                    JSONObject object3 = new JSONObject(property1);
                    actor.setHref(object3.getString("href"));
                    String href = object3.getString("href");
                    actor.setText(object3.getString("text"));
                    String text = object3.getString("text");
                    // Log.d("text", text);
                    Log.d("href", href);
                    Log.d("text",text);

                 actorsList.add(actor);////////////////not working



                }
            }
                else{
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}

public class Actors {
    private String text ;
    private String href;


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getHref() {
        return href;
    }

    public void setHref(String href) {
        this.href = href;
    }

    public Actors(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Just send data from onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask

Comment: Golden Rule : Don't touch anything that was declared outside of your `AsyncTask` from its `doInBackground` method. That method runs on a separate thread whereas your actorsList belongs to the main/UI thread. Attempting add an actor to the list means the background/worker thread is attempting to access the main thread - this isn't allowed. Instead create a local `ArrayList<Actors>` variable in the body of the `AsyncTask` and add the actors there. When the `doInBackground` method ends, `onPostExecute` is called (on the main thread) and you can copy the `ArrayList` over to the main one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify result of your doInBackground(now you have Boolean) an get this result in onPostExecute(which work at main thread)

```
public static class ActorsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<Actors>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Actors> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        //make request and get actors
        List<Actors> result = new ArrayList<Actors>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            Actrots actorsFromJson;
            //create actors object from JSON data
            result.add(actorsFromJson);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(List<Actors> result) {
        actorsList.addAll(result);
        //TODO processing data for display it. This is UI thread.
    }
}
```

**UPD:**
Your async task class is not inner class of the fragment, so, you have two way for solve this:

**1)** Create interface and set it to AsyncTask for get any reaction

```
public interface TaskResult {
    void onSuccess(List<Actors> result);
}
```

add new field `TaskResult taskResult;` in `ActorsAsyncTask` class

you can set value to it from constructor:

```
public ActorsAsyncTask(TaskResult taskResult) {
    this.taskResult = taskResult;
}
```

or from setter

```
public void setTaskResultCallback() {
    this.taskResult = taskResult;
}
```

and after that just call `taskResult.onSuccess(result);` from `onPostExecute`

**2)** You can change your `ActorsAsyncTask` signature to `public class ActorsAsyncTask`
and put it to `PlaceholderFragment2` class like:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment2 extends Fragment {
//some code here
    public class ActorsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
         //some code here
    }
}
```

if logic of your application can take it.

Comment: still i cannot access the actorsList from on post Execute